# In Angular 2, how to setup an asynchronous validator when using template-driven forms?

Tags: validation, angular

I've defined a directive for my asynchronous validator:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[validatorUsername]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ValidatorUsernameDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class ValidatorUsernameDirective implements Validator {
  validate(c: AbstractControl) {
    let username = c.value;

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if( username === "nemo" ) {
          resolve({
            'taken': true
          })
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

In template, I've applied it as follows:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required validatorUsername>
```

Then I've applied validation messages from code (not from template), as described in Angular's Cookbook, chapter [Form Validation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html):

```
export class App implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;

  name: string;
  username: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(_ => this.onValueChanged());
  }

  onValueChanged() {
    // fill 'formErrors' object
  }

  formErrors = {
    'name': '',
    'username': ''
  };
}
```

**The problem** is that `onValueChanged()` doesn't get called when validator's promise is resolved, thus the validation message for `username` does not appear. It appears though if you try to edit the `name` field. What should I do to trigger the update on UI?

**[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HMS9WjvW1hPZnBUXAGsb) is the plunker for my code.**

---

References:

- [Angular2 template driven async validator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36235446/6941051)
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html
- https://netbasal.com/angular-2-forms-create-async-validator-directive-dd3fd026cb45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to `statusChanges` event that is fired after calling async validator

```
this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(_=> this.onValueChanged());
```

**[Modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6x0vNWQLQYCxd7sAIouh?p=preview)**